# How can I make a unit test run in DEBUG mode only?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, debugging

I have a unit test that tests if an Exception is throw, but this Exception is only throw in Debug mode (via the [Conditional("DEBUG")] Attribute). If I run this test in Release mode, it fails. I tried to apply the same Attribute on the test but it's no taken into account.

How can I exclude a test in Release mode? Does it even make sense to run unit tests in Release mode or should I stick to Debug mode?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133988/make-mstest-respect-conditional-attribute

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As for most of your question, it depends somewhat on what unit testing tool your using.  However, in general what you want are [preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)

```
//C#
#ifndef DEBUG
    //Unit test
#endif
```

Perhaps for your situation

```
//C# - for NUnit
#if !DEBUG
    [Ignore("This test runs only in debug")] 
#endif
```

But as to whether to leave unit tests in the release version?  I'd give a resounding NO.  I'd suggest moving all your unit tests into it's own project and NOT including this in your releases.

Comment: Of course, all my unit tests are in another project, but I can still run them in Release mode...

Comment: Why would you really want them to be different in release and debug?

Comment: I want to be sure that me code will behave the same in Debug and in Release mode. But in this particular case, I *know* that the test will fail in Release mode since the Exception should only be thrown in Debug mode (by design)

Comment: Well, I came up with a possible solution, provided your using NUnit.

Comment: I ended up using your solution after all. Since I'm using MSTest, the Attribute is [Ignore] (no parameter).

Comment: This is a better solution that works in every environment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805464/are-there-nunit-test-case-attributes-for-specifying-configuration Just make a "DebugOnly" Category and exclude that from your Release build

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
#if DEBUG

// here is your test

#endif
```

Comment: This works but I think it's a too drastic solution. Instead, I used the [Ignore] Attribute (still, it's enclosed inside a #if !DEBUG ... #endif, but I like it better).

Answer (score 6):

If you're using NUnit, you can make your unit test methods conditional:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void UnitTestMethod()
{
   // Tests here
}
```

This way it will only be executed in DEBUG builds. I don't have a lot of experience with Visual Studio unit tests, but I'm pretty sure that this should work there in VS too.

**EDIT**: Others have mentionned conditional compilation directives. I don't think that it is a very good idea, for a number of reasons. To learn more about the differences between conditional compilation directives and the conditional attribute, read [Eric Lippert's excellent article here](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/10/what-s-the-difference-between-conditional-compilation-and-the-conditional-attribute.aspx).

Comment: I'm using MSTest and it looks like the Conditional Attribute is not honored by the test engine...

Comment: You could put the conditional attribute on a DoUnitTestMethod helper method, which you would call from UnitTestMethod. This would then become an empty test that always passes in Release mode. Gets trickier with things like [ExpectedException] though. Simplest just to use #if DEBUG around the whole test case.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using XUnit, you can use the following method [as described by Jimmy Bogard](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/06/20/run-tests-explicitly-in-xunit-net/) by extending the fact attribute:

```
public class RunnableInDebugOnlyAttribute : FactAttribute
{
    public RunnableInDebugOnlyAttribute()
    {
        if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Skip = "Only running in interactive mode.";
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can use this as follows:

```
[RunnableInDebugOnly]
public void Test_RunOnlyWhenDebugging()
{
    //your test code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar solution for NUnit framework(only debugging test works):

```
public class DebugOnlyAttribute : NUnitAttribute, IApplyToTest
{

    private const string _reason = "Debug only";

    public void ApplyToTest(Test test)
    {
        if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            test.RunState = RunState.Ignored;
            test.Properties.Set(PropertyNames.SkipReason, _reason);
        }

    }
}

[DebugOnly]
[Test]
public void TestMethod()
{ 
//your test code
}
```