# Make MSTest respect [Conditional()] attribute?

Tags: c#, mstest

I'm using VS2010, I have the following method call:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void VerboseLogging() { }

public void DoSomething() {
    VerboseLogging();
    Foo();
    Bar();
}
```

Then I have a unit test for the `DoSomething` method which checks that it emits proper logging.

```
[Conditional("DEBUG"), TestMethod()]
public void EnsureVerboseLog() {
    DoSomething();
    VerifyVerboseLoggingCalled(); // <-- fail in release builds since VerboseLogging() calls get eliminated.
}
```

It seems that MSTest only sees `TestMethod` and executes it (generating failed test) even though I've marked it with `Conditional("DEBUG")` and compile it in release mode.

**So, is there a way to exclude certain tests depending on compilation constant other than `#if`?**

Answer (score 8):

> So, is there a way to exclude certain tests depending on compilation
>   constant **other than #if**?

I'd use the #if - it's readable.

```
[TestMethod]
#if !DEBUG
[Ignore]
#endif
public void AnyTest()
{
    // Will invoke for developer and not in test-server!
}
```

HTH..

Comment: After a lot of searching many question and I was about to ask this very thing myself, this is the only answer that gives a specific solution on how to do unit testing with the condition of a symbol being present. Excellent answer!

Answer (score 7):

The `ConditionalAttribute` does not affect whether or not a method is compiled into an application.  It controls whether or not calls to the method are compiled into the application.

There is no call to `EnsureVerboseLog` in this sample.  MSTest just sees a method in the assemlby with the `TestMethod` attribute and correctly executes it.  In order to prevent MSTest from running the method you will need to do one of the following

1. Not compile it into your application (possible through #if's)
2. Not annotate it with the TestMethod attribute

Comment: msTest sucks a big one compared to MbUnit/Cairo , eh?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be able to conditionally run different tests, you will probably want to use the [`[TestCategory]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcategoryattribute?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) attribute:

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("SomeCategory")]
public void SomethingWorks()
{
    ...
}
```

And then use the [`filter` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=mstest) to include or exclude the categories:

```
dotnet test --filter "TestCategory=SomeCategory"
dotnet test --filter "TestCategory!=SomeCategory"
```

Answer (score 1):

A work around is to set the `Priority` attribute to -1 to your method. Then run `mstest` with "minpriority:0" as an argument.

```
[TestMethod()]
[Priority(-1)]
public void Compute_Foo()
{
    This method will not be executed
}
```