# Are there NUnit Test Case Attributes for specifying Configuration

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am writing an NUnit test that I want run only in the Release configuration. Is there an elegant way of doing this with a test case attribute?  Right now, I am surrounding the entire function block with compiler directives:

I am using Nunit 2.5.6.10205.

```
#if !DEBUG
        [Test]
        public void MyReleaseOnlyTest()
        {
           // stuff
        }
#endif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `[Category]` attribute. If you mark release only tests with `[Category("Release")]` then exclude that category in your normal test run and include it in you release run.

So now your test becomes

```
[Test]
[Category("Release")]
public void MyReleaseOnlyTest()
{
   // stuff
}
```

Comment: Roger that, thanks. Are you the Michael Two that I see on my Nunit Console? :)

Comment: @Stealth Rabbi - Guilty. I'm no longer active on the project though.

Answer (score 3):

Add the Ignore attribute in #if preprocessor, rather than the entire test method.

```
#if DEBUG
[Ignore("Only to be run in release")] 
#endif
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

You can also use the `Conditional` attribute

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("RELEASE")]
```

Comment: I like this as well, as it doesn't require changes to the nunit runner to exclude categories.