# nunit-console does not run tests parameterized with TestCase attribute

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

Trying to run Nunit tests parameterized with TestCase attribute. Something like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyClass
{
    [Test]
    [TestCase("option1")]
    [TestCase("option2")]
    public void Test1(string id)
    {

    }
}
```

And when I am trying to run this tests using nunit console

**nunit-console.exe MyProject.dll /run:MyNamespace.MyClass.Test1**

it works fine. But at attempt to run it parameterized:

**nunit-console.exe MyProject.dll /run:MyNamespace.MyClass.Test1("option1")**

it just shows:

*Tests run: 0, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0.0269838 seconds
Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0*

Comment: Take a look at this link StackOverFlow, perhaps you could try using a different Attribute http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805464/are-there-nunit-test-case-attributes-for-specifying-configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I remember it needs to be quoted a bit differently;

```
nunit-console.exe MyProject.dll /run:"MyNamespace.MyClass.Test1(\"option1\")"
```

Comment: If you have multiple parameters, make sure that you don't put a space after the delimiting commas. It should be like this: `nunit-console.exe MyProject.dll /run:"MyNamespace.MyClass.Test1(\"option1\",\"option2\",\"option3\")"`.

Comment: Also, make sure that the parameters you are passing actually exist together as a TestFixture in the code! Arrrg...