# Parameterized test using nunit3-console.exe with TestCase attribute

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-console

I am trying to run nunit3 parameterized test using TestCase attribute.

My Test method looks like:

```
[Test]
        [TestCase("testuser")]
        public void OBA_Test(String name)
        {
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10000));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + somewebsite)
            // Code to test website. 
        }
```

Then I take the dll and try to run using

```
nunit3-console.exe "C:\temp\test\Selenium Testing Prod.dll" /run:"SeleniumTests.SeleniunProdTest.OBA_Test(\"testuser\")"
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Any pointers ?

Ref: [nunit-console does not run tests parameterized with TestCase attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404919/nunit-console-does-not-run-tests-parameterized-with-testcase-attribute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message is telling you that there is no `/run` option recognized by the version of NUnit you are using. The `/run` of NUnit V2 was replaced by the enhanced `/test` option in NUnit 3.

Comment: Sorry for the delay response. I used Nunit3 and it was all good.
I used TestContext.Parameters.Get("variable") to get input from command line and then use --params.

I am accepting your response as solution and will also post my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was using nunit version 2 which is missing some feature. I updated to version 3 and followed this article :
http://executeautomation.com/blog/passing-parameters-to-nunit-test-via-cli-using-params/

essentially in my  [Setup] I collected my command line input as :

```
name = TestContext.Parameters.Get("empname");
```

and used this in my [Test] and used --params in commandline as below:

```
nunit3-console.exe --params:empname=testemp "C:\temp\Debug_PROD\Selenium Testing Prod.dll"
```